# ipython indentation problem on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, python

I seem to be getting an odd problem when using iPython sometimes.

Every time I try to go one line up or down (i.e. navigating through history or previous statements) it seems to put my cursor and the code in the middle of the screen, that ofcourse gives indentation errors.

Screenshot of the problem:

[image: alt]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Strange. Are you using Python at `/usr/bin/python`? How did you install IPython? As a sanity check, can you try using another terminal app like [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around found out that "readlines" can cause such problems when installed via pip (on mac OS).

I removed current ipython and "readlines" lib and reinstalled them using "easy_install" which fixed the problem.

Comment: Good to hear, glad it works.